# Errors "Sandbox deny iokit-get-properties" in IOS8

Tags: ios, xcode, ios8, sandbox

I have a strange behaviour when I debug my iPads on an app I'm programming, and I'm pretty sure this appeared only after updating all of the production ones to iOS8.

I am using Multipeer Connectivity, and tried debugging random disconnections, I ended up seeing the device's console long. I noticed there were always a bunch of them just before or after the disconnection (by bunch I mean from two dozen to hundreds of lines).

Also, my app uses background services, I don't know if it's related, but this required me to edit the app's configuration (in Xcode) to enable it as well as updating my certificate.

So, why are these "Sandbox deny iokit-get-properties" messages appearing?

Thank you.

An excerpt of the long messages:

`[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties HiddenInterface
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceState
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IONetworkData
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceNamePrefix
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOBuiltin
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOLocation
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IORequiredPacketFilters
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOActivePacketFilters
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceType
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMaxTransferUnit
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceFlags
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceExtraFlags
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediaAddressLength
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediaHeaderLength
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOInterfaceUnit
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOPrimaryInterface
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties BSD Name
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOClass
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOPropertyMatch
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOProviderClass
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties CFBundleIdentifier
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOProbeScore
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMatchCategory
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOActiveMedium
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOSelectedMedium
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOLinkStatus
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOLinkSpeed
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMediumDictionary
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOFeatures
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMaxPacketSize
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMinPacketSize
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOPacketFilters
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOMACAddress
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOGeneralInterest
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties HostAttached
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties USBDeviceFunction
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties StartedTimestamp
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IsActive
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOCFPlugInTypes
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties IOUserClientClass
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties FinalizedTimestamp
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties FinalizedDurationMS
[date] [iPad name] kernel[0] <Notice>: Sandbox: [My App Name]([Process number]) deny iokit-get-properties NetworkConfigurationOverrides`

Answer (score 0):

This should not be happening unless you are trying to access restricted IOKit properties from your app. The sandbox on iOS doesn't completely block IOKit and the IO Registry, but it looks like Apple has selected specific nodes and values that should be denied. What you're seeing here is the values that got denied, but it's possible that other values ARE getting through okay.

If you are not doing anything with IOKit directly, then this might actually be the Multipeer Connectivity framework that's making those calls, in which case this issue is likely already fixed by now.